# How to retrieve indexes of an already existing MongoDB collection and then passing it back to a recreated version of it - in Java?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I need to Drop a MongoDB collection and then Re-create it with the same indexes it had before. However I don't want to hardcode the indexes; I want to automatically retrieve the indexes, store them somewhere, and the pass them back after collection is dropped and recreated. This program will run everynight via a cron job. Here's where I am stuck:

```
<MONGO Connector code...>
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);
MongoCollection<Document> collectionX = mongoDatabase.getCollection("XCollection");
ListIndexesIterable<Document> indexes = collectionX.listIndexes();
collectionX.drop();
mongoDatabase.createCollection("XCollection");
collectionX.createIndex(indexes); //Throws exception "createIndex (org.bson.conversions.Bson) in MongoCollection cannot be applied to (com.mongodb.client.ListIndexesIterable<org.bson.Document>)"
-----------------------------------------------------------
Another way...
for (Document document : indexes) {
        collectionX.createIndex(document);
    }
This throws error too: Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 67: 'Unknown index plugin '_id_'' on server XX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXXX. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unknown index plugin '_id_'", "code" : 67, "codeName" : "CannotCreateIndex" }
```

Comment: Why not run `yourcollection.remove({})` instead? It'll delete all existing documents in your collection while retaining all of the indexes. If that's not feasible for any reason, including a performance one, then someone else may be able to provide a process matching what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, it's a performance issue.